# MPI4Py causes error on send/recv

Tags: python, mpi

Can someone tell me why this minimal working example (MWE) complains of `TypeError: expected a writeable buffer object`?

**MWE:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from mpi4py import MPI

# MPI Initialization
rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD

if __name__ == '__main__':
   a = True
   if rank == 0:
      a = False
      comm.Send ( [ a, MPI.BOOL ], 1, 111 )
   if rank == 1:
      comm.Recv ([ a, MPI.BOOL], 0, 111 )
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    comm.Recv ([ a, MPI.BOOL], 0, 111 )
  File "Comm.pyx", line 143, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Recv (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:62980)
  File "message.pxi", line 323, in mpi4py.MPI.message_p2p_recv (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:22814)
  File "message.pxi", line 309, in mpi4py.MPI._p_msg_p2p.for_recv (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:22665)
  File "message.pxi", line 111, in mpi4py.MPI.message_simple (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:20516)
  File "message.pxi", line 51, in mpi4py.MPI.message_basic (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:19644)
  File "asbuffer.pxi", line 108, in mpi4py.MPI.getbuffer (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:6757)
  File "asbuffer.pxi", line 48, in mpi4py.MPI.PyObject_GetBufferEx (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:6081)
TypeError: expected a writeable buffer object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    comm.Send ( [ a, MPI.BOOL ], 1, 111 )
  File "Comm.pyx", line 132, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Send (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:62796)
  File "message.pxi", line 318, in mpi4py.MPI.message_p2p_send (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:22744)
  File "message.pxi", line 301, in mpi4py.MPI._p_msg_p2p.for_send (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:22604)
  File "message.pxi", line 111, in mpi4py.MPI.message_simple (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:20516)
  File "message.pxi", line 51, in mpi4py.MPI.message_basic (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:19644)
  File "asbuffer.pxi", line 108, in mpi4py.MPI.getbuffer (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:6757)
  File "asbuffer.pxi", line 50, in mpi4py.MPI.PyObject_GetBufferEx (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:6093)

===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   EXIT CODE: 1
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
[proxy:0:0@raspi1] HYD_pmcd_pmip_control_cmd_cb (./pm/pmiserv/pmip_cb.c:886): assert (!closed) failed
[proxy:0:0@raspi1] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (./tools/demux/demux_poll.c:77): callback returned error status
[proxy:0:0@raspi1] main (./pm/pmiserv/pmip.c:206): demux engine error waiting for event
[mpiexec@raspi1] HYDT_bscu_wait_for_completion (./tools/bootstrap/utils/bscu_wait.c:76): one of the processes terminated badly; aborting
[mpiexec@raspi1] HYDT_bsci_wait_for_completion (./tools/bootstrap/src/bsci_wait.c:23): launcher returned error waiting for completion
[mpiexec@raspi1] HYD_pmci_wait_for_completion (./pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_pmci.c:217): launcher returned error waiting for completion
[mpiexec@raspi1] main (./ui/mpich/mpiexec.c:331): process manager error waiting for completion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why I am getting the above error, so if anyone does know, please answer and I will accept. That being said, I can get the code to work if I use this style instead (old code commented out):

**MWE:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from mpi4py import MPI

# MPI Initialization
rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD

if __name__ == '__main__':
   a = True
   if rank == 0:
      a = False
      # comm.Send ( [ a, MPI.BOOL ], dest=1, tag=111 )
      comm.send ( a, dest=1, tag=111 )
   if rank == 1:
      # comm.Recv ([ a, MPI.BOOL], dest=0, tag=111 )
      a = comm.recv (source=0, tag=111 )
```

Comment: Your problematic code differs in your 2 examples.  
    `comm.Send ( [ a, MPI.BOOL ], 1, 111 )`  
vs.  
    `# comm.Send ( [ a, MPI.BOOL ], dest=1, tag=111 )`  
Did simply including the field labels fix your issue?

Comment: That could be why. Note that I used `send` first and it crashed, then `Send` crashed, then I went back to `send` and it worked. I guess the field labels **are** what made the difference. Let me double check

Comment: @kraffenetti I just tried it again using the upper case versions `Send/Recv`, and I fixed the `dest` to `source` in the second commented line, and I **still** got the same error

Comment: It looks as if mpi4py expects a buffer-provider object in the uppercase Send/Recv calls. Since you are using generic Python objects in your example, you should stick to the lowercase calls.

http://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an MPI expert, but I wonder if the boolean datatype in numpy is not compatible with the boolean datatype in C? Perhaps this is what causes the error. (Not proof, but some evidence: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html#arrays-scalars-built-in and https://cython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html)

puk, as you noted, one solution is to transfer the data as python objects using the `send`send and `recv` (with lowercase s and r) functions (http://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/tutorial.html). "Under the hood," mpi4py uses `pickle` for this, and therefore any generic python object can be sent.

My main reason to answer is to post an alternative solution using integer arrays, with 0 corresponding to True and 1 to False:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI

# MPI Initialization
rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a=np.array([0,])
    if rank == 0:
        a[0]=1
        comm.Send( [ a, MPI.INT ], 1, tag=111 )
        print rank,a
    if rank == 1:
        comm.Recv([ a, MPI.INT], 0, tag=111 )
        print rank,a
```

in case one wants to take advantage of the faster (according to the `mpi4py` docs) numpy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The uppercase functions of MPI accept butter like objects such as NumPy arrays in python. The lowercase functions use pickle in order to being able to send the objects.

http://mpi4py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html