# mpi4py - MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated

Tags: python-2.7, openmpi, mpi4py

I converted the ring_c.c code from OPENMPI examples in python to experiment with mpi4py. Here is my code.

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

next_proc = (rank + 1) % size
prev_proc = (rank + size - 1) % size

tag = 2
message = 10

if 0 == rank:
    comm.send(message, dest=next_proc, tag=tag)

while(1):
    message = comm.recv(message, source=prev_proc, tag=tag)  
    comm.Recv_init

    if 0 == rank:
        message = message - 1
        print "Process %d decremented value: %d\n" %(rank, message)

    comm.send(message, dest=next_proc, tag=tag)

    if 0 == message:
        print "Process %d exiting\n" %(rank)
        break;

if 0 == rank:
    message = comm.recv(message, source=prev_proc, tag=tag)
```

When I run it via mpiexec for any number of processes, for example

```
mpiexec -n 10 python ring_py.py
```

It gives the following output and error:

```
Process 0 decremented value: 9

Process 0 decremented value: 8

Process 0 decremented value: 7

Process 0 decremented value: 6

Process 0 decremented value: 5

Process 0 decremented value: 4

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ring_py.py", line 20, in <module>
    message = comm.recv(message, source=prev_proc, tag=tag)  
  File "MPI/Comm.pyx", line 1192, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.recv (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:106889)
  File "MPI/msgpickle.pxi", line 287, in mpi4py.MPI.PyMPI_recv (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:42965)
mpi4py.MPI.Exception: MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated
```

A couple of observations

- If I change the message to say 6 or 50, it always throws out the same error at Process 0 decremented value: 4
- If I change the message value to say 4 or less, it throws out the same error without doing anything else.
- The number of processes has no effect on the output of the code, other than the execution time.

A few details about my system.

- I am using MacBook Air 2012 model with macOS Sierra and Intel i7 core processor.
- I installed mpi4py via PIP in python 2.7 and its version is 2.0.0

Can someone please help me understand what is going on with my code.

Thank you,
Jayant

Comment: FWIW: I mostly get truncated errors when the buffersize in the receive op are off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and I got an error at:

```
message = comm.recv(message, source=prev_proc, tag=tag)
```

Stating:

> TypeError: expected a writeable buffer object

Following the [tutorial of mpi4py](https://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/tutorial.html) or [MPI4Py causes error on send/recv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371239/mpi4py-causes-error-on-send-recv) , I successfully tried:

```
message = comm.recv( source=prev_proc, tag=tag)
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Francis, I was able to solve the mystery. I know that Python is case-sensitive even then I missed the fact that there are two distinct sets of functions for sending and receiving messages. Send/Recv use Numpy array while send/recv use pickle under the hood.

So, the first version i.e. Numpy version could be:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()
next_proc = (rank + 1) % size
prev_proc = (rank + size - 1) % size
tag = 2
message = np.array([0,])
message[0] = 10
if 0 == rank:
    print "Process %d sending %d to %d, tag %d (%d processes in ring)\n" %(rank, message, next_proc, tag, size)
    comm.Send([message, MPI.INT], dest=next_proc, tag=tag)

while(1):
    comm.Recv([message, MPI.INT], source=prev_proc, tag=tag)

    if 0 == rank:
        message = message - 1
        print "Process %d decremented value: %d\n" %(rank, message)

    comm.Send([message, MPI.INT], dest=next_proc, tag=tag)

    if 0 == message[0]:
        print "Process %d exiting\n" %(rank)
        break;
```

The second version i.e. pickle version could be:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

next_proc = (rank + 1) % size
prev_proc = (rank + size - 1) % size

tag = 2
message = 10

if 0 == rank:
    print "Process %d sending %d to %d, tag %d (%d processes in ring)\n" %(rank, message, next_proc, tag, size)
    comm.send(message, dest=next_proc, tag=tag)        

while(1):
    message = comm.recv(source=prev_proc, tag=tag)

    if 0 == rank:
        message = message - 1
        print "Process %d decremented value: %d\n" %(rank, message)

    comm.send(message, dest=next_proc, tag=tag)

    if 0 == message:
        print "Process %d exiting\n" %(rank)
        break;
```

Both the versions will give the same output. The difference will be in their execution time as per the MPI tutorial which says that Numpy version will be faster.